# Not Updating The Image Doesn't Update The Record

Tags: yii-extensions, yii, yii-components, yii-events

The problem is if I want to update the other fields and not the image. It passes the validation and doesn't update any of the fields.

***But if I update the image and other fields it updates.  Or if i update the image it updates.***

View:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'pimg'); ?>
<?php echo $form->fileField($model, 'pimg',array('id'=>'imgInput',)); ?>    
<?php echo $form->error($model,'pimg'); ?>
```

Controller:

```
public function actionEdit($id)
{
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    if(isset($_POST['Product']))
    {
        $model->pimg=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'pimg');  
        $fileName=$model->pimg;
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Product'];
        if($model->save())
            $model->pimg->saveAs('images/'.$fileName);
            $this->redirect(array('display','id'=>$model->productid));
        }
        $this->render('edit',array('model'=>$model,));
    }
```

Model rules:

```
array('name, category, model, brand, description, price', 'required'),
array('pimg', 'file','types'=>'jpg','on'=>'create', 'allowEmpty'=>false),
array('pimg', 'file','types'=>'jpg','on'=>'update', 'allowEmpty'=>true),
```

I think the problem is with the controller.  I keep getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object in  D:\wamp\www\testfolder\protected\controllers\ProductController.php on line 147

 line 147:  $model->pimg->saveAs('images/'.$fileName);
```

Image appears but then image name from db doesn't appear next to the choose file button renders stating no file chosen.

Note that I am new to Yii, and am stuck with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `actionEdit` i.e here

```
$model->pimg=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'pimg');     
         $fileName=$model->pimg;
          $model->attributes=$_POST['Product'];
        if($model->save())
        $model->pimg->saveAs('images/'.$fileName);
```

here you should check if the image has been uploaded or not. what happens is that yii is unable to execute this line  `$model->pimg->saveAs('images/'.$fileName);` as no image has been uploaded. so you need to wrap it inside a condition i.e

```
if(!empty($model->pimg))
{
$model->pimg->saveAs('images/'.$fileName);
}
```

so your **final code should be something like this**

```
$model->attributes=$_POST['Product'];
 $model->pimg=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'pimg');     
    if(!empty($model->pimg))
    {
     $fileName=$model->pimg->name;
                $model->pimg->saveAs('images/'.$fileName);
    }
if($model->save())
//render here
```

**Update 1**
If you want that on update null should not be stored in your database then you can do this

```
$model=$this->loadModel($id);
$prevImage=$model->pimg;  //add this line
```

and then where you are using this

```
if(!empty($model->pimg))
{
$model->pimg->saveAs('images/'.$fileName);
}
else{
$model->pimg=$prevIMage;
}
```

add this **else code**

Comment: thanx :) ya absolutely true ...... am done ... but the above code needs some more modification n what if image not updated it wont save the existing image .... results null stored in db ... if(image exist && not uploaded){//save code}else {///save uploaded image} ...... thats it

Comment: em glad that it helped :)

Comment: If this answer is the solution to your question, you should mark it as such.